# Anchor tags don't work and stay selected until I click again

Tags: html, css

I'm creating some sort of dashboard which gives the different statuses for data. If you click a status only the objects with that status should be shown. Right now I still have

```
<a href="#">*TEXT*</a>
```

for all the anchors. But when I click them my URL doesn't change and when I move my cursor to a different location the text is still underlined.

[image]

The first underlined rule in the image is a hover, the last one is the one I clicked before. Now only after I click somewhere else, even empty parts on the website, the underlining goes away.

Does anyone know why this occurs and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/xcjufs6e/

Comment: Its working if you have given any url instead of `#` see http://jsfiddle.net/xcjufs6e/1/

Comment: It should work with # still.

Comment: @Manwal The links aren't supposed to refer to a certain website, their functionalities will call AJAX functions. But as I'm still working on the PoC I only have to do design for now.

Comment: @SleekGeek But it doesn't, I have tried putting an empty div with id on top, make the last anchor (green) refer to this id. And then after I scroll down and click I'm not even directed to the top of the page :-/

Comment: What is that you are expecting? Bootstrap underlines the anchor on focus.

Comment: @anpsmn I expect that after I click the URL of my page changes and the anchor doesn't remain underlined. So you mean to say that the fact my anchor remains underlined is a bootstrap setting?

Comment: @Gravinco Yes, if you see [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1096) the anchor on focus is underlined.

Comment: @anpsmn Indeed, that was the problem. I've posted an answer with the solution I used

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by adding these lines in the CSS

```
.conexio-info-message a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.conexio-info-message a:focus:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```